# Is it possible to increase specificity host selector shadow root custom element?

Tags: html, css, shadow-dom, custom-element

Hee everyone,

I have the following page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <style>
            @layer reset {
                * {
                    padding: 0;
                }
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            class Webcomponent extends HTMLElement {
                constructor() {
                    super();
                    this.attachShadow({mode: "open"})

                    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = 
                    `
                        <style>
                            :host {
                                padding: 40px;
                            }
                        </style>
                        <div>hee</div>
                    `;
                }
            }

            customElements.define('web-component', Webcomponent);
        </script>

        <web-component></web-component>
    </body>
</html>
```

The host selector of the custom element is styled with a padding of 40px. In the light-DOM there is a stylesheet with a reset of the padding. The way it is currently structured the reset will overwrite the host selector styles.

[image: css specificity]

My question is, is there a way to flip these layers? So that the host selector css will have a higher specificity then the reset.

Comment: No, this is how ``layer`` works. The Web Component is no different than a normal ``div`` with styles on it. So set the padding on the DIV _inside_ the shadowRoot, or abuse ``!important``

Comment: or execute ``this.style.padding = "40px"`` in the connectecCallback